# how to select the entire document using querySelector

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsdom

how to select the entire document using querySelector

Here is the code:

```
var jsdom = require('jsdom');
const {JSDOM} = jsdom;
const dom = new JSDOM(htmlSource)
var q = dom.window.document.querySelector.bind(dom.window.document);
q("title").innerHTML = "This is the title replaced"
console.log(q("html").outerHTML);
htmlSource = q("html").outerHTML;
fs.writeFileSync("public/html/index2.html", htmlSource, "utf8");
```

I want to rewrite the changed `title` element into the new file `index2.html`. I am able to output the changed element but not able to write the new version of the file. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can change it like this `dom.window.document.title = "new title"`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/title

Comment: I know that i can use jQery to manipulate the dom, but how to apply the changes to the file afterward?